# PHP array of arrays: get a list of values for a given attribute

Tags: php, arrays

suppose i have an array of arrays in PHP:

```
$array = [
    ['value'=>1, 'other_attribute'=>'whatever'],
    ['value'=>13, 'other_attribute'=>'whatever'],
    ['value'=>45, 'other_attribute'=>'whatever'],
    ['value'=>64, 'other_attribute'=>'whatever'],
];
```

how can i get a list containing just a specific attribute of each of the array's elements? in my case, if i wanted to get the list of 'value', the output should look like this:
`[1, 13, 45, 64]`

using the [Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/), it's easy to do this with [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) objects, simply like this: `$array->lists('value');`. is there a way to do this in plain PHP?

Comment: And check the highest scoring answer for the duplicate, rather than simply the accepted answer

Comment: `array_column($array, 'value');`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just build your own loop to do it:

```
$values = []; // the new array where we'll store the 'value' attributes
foreach ($array as $a) { // let's loop through the array you posted in your question
    $values[] = $a['value']; // push the value onto the end of the array
}
```

Comment: `$values = array_column($array, 'value');` is much easier